# Python NLTK and Categorization of RSS feeds ?

Tags: python, rss, nltk

I have been trying to find libraries that do categorization of articles to specific categories, and have been having no luck, the closest project I could find was this link from IBM
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-pythonnltk/index.html

Which is exactly what I need to do but, the code is incomplete,

Is there a library that provides RSS feed categorization?

Comment: Mike, the code is not really incomplete. It is just that the post presents it in chunks. Try to put all the chunks together in one file. If you run into difficulties, ask here.

Comment: Thanks Ram sorry I was a lacking a bit of sleep yesturday.